# Unable to link a self-executing function with html?

Tags: javascript, html

I am very new to Java Script. I am studying with the help of video lectures, and trying to solve the examples discussed. In the chapter Anonymous Self executing function, I am unable to link self execute function.
My codes are as follows:
Html::

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8"; 
    </head>
<body>

    <p id="message"> 
    </p>

    <script src="my2.js"> </script>
    <script src="my.js"> </script>
</body>
</html>
```

my.js:

```
( function()
{

    function Format(num) {
        return Math.floor(num);
    }

    ShowMessage("You are viewing a lesson in section" + Format(9.1));

}());
```

my2.js:

```
functon ShowMessage(msg)
{
    document.getElementById("message").innerHTML += Format(msg);

}

function Format(msg)
{
    return "<p>" + msg + "</p>";
}
```

Please help me.

Comment: Did you open the console and check for errors.

Comment: Go through http://markdalgleish.com/2011/03/self-executing-anonymous-functions/

Comment: I'll give you a tip : It's spelled ***function*** !

Comment: @adeneo I am getting this at console: Use of getPreventDefault() is deprecated.  Use defaultPrevented instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this it?

```
(function()
{

    function Format(num) {
        return Math.floor(num);
    }

    ShowMessage("You are viewing a lesson in section" + Format(9.1));

})();
```

I think you messed the brackets.

Still, this happens in javascript because you are evaluating a function as an expression. 
This means that your function is only giving scope to a piece of code, and since you call it after closing de scope `})();`, it gets evaluated as an expression.

Following that logic, you can even do:

```
!function()
{

    function Format(num) {
        return Math.floor(num);
    }

    ShowMessage("You are viewing a lesson in section" + Format(9.1));

}();
```

That the function is also run.

[EDIT] You missed the closing '>' in your meta tag too.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you've got a few typos in your code:

In your `HTML` code (line 5):

```
<meta charset="UTF-8"> <!-- ">" instead of ";" -->
```

In `my2.js`:

```
function ShowMessage(msg) { // you forgot an "i" in your code
```

The first one will be corrected automatically in most browsers (however: you should avoid this). But the second one will raise an error and you can't call `ShowMessage()` anymore.

Answer (score 0):

You misspelled function in my2.js

```
function ShowMessage(msg)
{
    document.getElementById("message").innerHTML += Format(msg);
}
function Format(msg)
{
    return "<p>" + msg + "</p>";
}
```